# Can mutt set the color of some messages in the inbox?

Tags: mutt

Is it possible to configure Mutt so that the message index shows some messages in a different colour?

For example, if a message is received with a subject line matching the pattern `^Foo`, set that message to appear yellow in the inbox list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's possible. First you define the colour and pattern to match:

```
set my_pattern = "color index green black ~s ^Foo"
```

Then you set this pattern as a folder-hook for the particular folder and undo
it for all other folders:

```
folder-hook .      un$my_pattern
folder-hook .Inbox $my_pattern
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank-you. I am using mutt 1.5.21 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS, and needed to set `my_pattern` to `'color index green black "~s \"^Foo\""'` and change `.Inbox` in the second folder-hook directive to `.INBOX` or `""!""` for it to work.